# How to set the width of kendogrid group columns

Tags: javascript, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have been working with a KendoGrid that has two levels of group as in the image:

[image: Kendogrid two group columns]

What I need to do now is reduce the width on the group columns.

I test this code using jquery:

```
$(".k-group-col,.k-group-cell").css('width', 10)
```

...and it works but just for a moment. (Probably there is a kendo function that reset that width.)

Please help. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue with large group columns is most often caused by all other columns having explicit widths, which are too small, so their sum is less than the Grid's total width. In such cases the browser expands the columns.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/appearance#columns

Either leave at least one column with no width, or set larger column widths. No custom CSS will be necessary.

Update: the group columns already have a default width, that is adequately small.

Comment: Thanks @dimodi, this works for the width on the group columns, but then I lost the width aspect proportion on others column, bs now the width is getting according the content.

Comment: Do you have Grid scrolling enabled or disabled?

Comment: enabled (//scrollable: false,)

Comment: Also I dont know if this affects, but I have been using this code: $(".gridJobReport").data("kendoGrid").wrapper.find(".k-grid-header-wrap").off("scroll.kendoGrid") from  http://www.telerik.com/forums/horizontal-scroll-is-not-smooth-in-kendo-grid

Comment: If scrolling is enabled, the table layout is "fixed". All columns without widths are equally wide, and the set columns are obeyed. No column widths should depends on their content. Glad I've helped.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this:

I have created an example with dynamic widths (so column-widths can be ratios and do not have to be explicit widths)

http://jsfiddle.net/2cf1w0t8/

Here is the column definition and the event in dataBound which sets the "group col" width.

```
dataBound: function(e){
            e.sender.element.find(".k-group-col,.k-group-cell").css('width', 2)
        },
        columns: [
            {
                field: "HistoryDate",
                groupHeaderTemplate: function(args){
                    return '<span class="row_'+args.uid+'">' + kendo.toString(args.value, 'dd.MM.yyyy') + '</span>';
                },
                hidden: true,
                filterable: false,
                width: 0
            },
            {
                field: "Titelbezeichnung",
                template: function(items){
                    return items.Titelbezeichnung + '<br>' + (items.Titelbezeichnung2 ? items.Titelbezeichnung2 : '&nbsp;');
                },
                width: 30,
            },
            {
                field: "ISIN",
                filterable: false,
                width: 10,
            },
            {
                field: "Valor",
                filterable: false,
                width: 10,
            },
            {
                field: "Ticker",
                width: 10,
            },
            {
                field: "SecurityCCY",
                attributes:{ align:"center" }, headerAttributes: { 'class': 'k-header-centeralign' },
                filterable: false,
                width: 10,
            },
            {
                field: "RiskCCY",
                attributes:{ align:"center" }, headerAttributes: { 'class': 'k-header-centeralign' },
                filterable: false,
                width: 10,
            },
            {
                field: "Typ",
                filterable: false,
                width: 10,
            },
            {
                field: "LastPrice",
                attributes:{ align:"right" }, headerAttributes: { 'class': 'k-header-rightalign' },
                filterable: false,
                format: '{0:n4}',
                width: 10,
            },
            {
                field: "PriceDate",
                attributes:{ align:"right" }, headerAttributes: { 'class': 'k-header-rightalign' },
                filterable: false,
                format: "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}",
                width: 10,
            },
            {
                field: "Status",
                attributes:{ align:"right" }, headerAttributes: { 'class': 'k-header-rightalign' },
                filterable: false,
                width: 10,
            },
            {
                field: "Percentage",
                attributes:{ align:"right" }, headerAttributes: { 'class': 'k-header-rightalign' }, footerAttributes: { align: 'right' }, groupFooterAttributes: { align: 'right' },
                format: "{0:n2}",
                editor: editNumberDecimals,

                aggregates: ["sum"],
                groupFooterTemplate: '<span class="footerPercentage">#=sum#%</span>',
                filterable: false,
                width: 20,
            },
            //{ command: {name: "destroy", text: ' '}, title: " ", attributes:{ align:"right" }, headerAttributes:{'style':'text-align: right'}, },
        ]
```